# rollback does not work with tomcat using JOTM

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, transactions, jta, jotm

I was using oc4j for development of a weba application involving JSP, servlets and JDBC (dayabase: oracle 11gr2). Had used built in transaction manager and commits and rollbacks used to work fine.

However, due to licensing we are now supposed to move the code to a free server like tomcat. I have implemented JOTM as the transaction manager in tomcat following the steps in this post:

http://codepitbull.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/tomcat-7-with-full-jta/

The following is the configuration in %CATALINA_HOME%/conf/context.xml

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/ticketds" 
              auth="Container" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"
              maxActive="30" 
              minIdle="2" 
              maxWait="10000" 
              initialSize="10"
              defaultAutoCommit="false"
              username="xxxx" 
              password="xxxxx" 
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxx.xxxx.com:iiii/xyz"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/taskds" 
              auth="Container" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"
              maxActive="30" 
              minIdle="2" 
              maxWait="10000" 
              initialSize="10"
              defaultAutoCommit="false"
              username="apps" 
              password="few1idna" 
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxx.xxxx.com:iiii/xyz"/>

  <Transaction factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory"
               jotm.timeout="600"/>
```

The web.xml is configured to mention the datasource in resource-refs like so:

```
    <resource-ref>
    <description>Ticket Datasource configuration</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/ticketds</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <description>SR Datasource configuration</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/taskds</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

However, when i try to perform rollbacks, it does not help. Here is a sample test code for rollback that i am using for testing:

```
UserTransaction utx = DBUtil.getUserTransaction();
    Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
    TicketMessageVO newTicket = null;

    try {
        utx.begin();

        newTicket = new TicketDAO(conn).createTicket(ticket);


        // testing only
        if(1==1) throw new Exception("Testing transaction rollback");

        utx.commit();

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Ticket created successfully: " + ticket.getMessageId());

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        utx.rollback();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error in creating ticket: ", e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResources(null, null, conn);
    }

    return newTicket;
```

The same bit of code used to work perfectly with oc4j. Am i missing something in the configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Using Atomikos for now. Works very well and documented properly. Still open to suggestions on this question though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently run into the same issue and I solved it using JOTM's own datasource factory (`org.objectweb.jotm.datasource.DataSourceFactory`) instead of Tomcat's. This is how your context.xml should look like:

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/taskds" 
          auth="Container" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.objectweb.jotm.datasource.DataSourceFactory" 
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          maxActive="30" 
          minIdle="2" 
          maxWait="10000" 
          initialSize="10"
          defaultAutoCommit="false"
          username="apps" 
          password="few1idna" 
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxx.xxxx.com:iiii/xyz"/>
```

However, using JOTM this way causes Tomcat to hang during shutdown (maybe due to a non-daemon thread in Carol).